# Recorrido de un array y obtener el objeto que se encuentre en ese índice a una función que tiene de parámetro un objeto?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando recorrer un array, obtener el objeto en el índice que se encuentre para poder pasarlo a una función que de parámetro recibe un objeto para proceder a leerlo y posteriormente con los distintos valores que se encuentran en el objeto mapearlos o dibujarlos para presentarlos después con ayuda del `.innerHTML()`.

Estoy pensando en utilizar funciones tipo flecha ya que el resto del script tiene implementadas ya otras funciones flechas las cuales ya se encuentran funcionando.

Este pedazo de código es lo que tengo actualmente:

```
var listGrabada = localStorage.getItem('listaC');
var listaG = JSON.parse(listGrabada);
listaG.forEach( obj => {
   leerData(obj)
   ...
   ...
});
```

ya tengo la función que recibe un objeto, **quisiera saber si está bien el planteamiento de la función flecha o si debería usar un bucle for en reemplazo para obtener el objeto de cada índice y poder pasarlo a la función que va a leer la información que hay dentro de cada objeto**

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, cual es la finalidad, saber si esta bien tu codigo o saber si el utilizar row function es correcto?

Comment: Si lo que tienes en localStorage como `listaC` es un arreglo tu código funcionará sin problemas. En cambio si `listaC` es un objeto literal, tu código no funcionará. Los objetos literales no incluyen la función `forEach`.

Comment: Ya recupero la lista del localstorage y la parseo para poder seleccionar cada objeto y pasarlo en la función para leerla, en sí mi pregunta va más enfocada a cómo obtener cada objeto en una función flecha y si se podía utilizar el forEach para llevar a cabo el obtenerlo y pasarlo a otra función.

Comment: Gracias @Jaime Menéndez por aclararme el porque no funcionaría.